# Import library not found in databricks notebook

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, databricks, azure-databricks

using Azure Devops pipeline task, I'm importing azure.databricks.cicd.tools library and installing azure-identity and azure-keyvault-secrets. These libraries are installed fine on to a cluster when I add it to a cluster using a bearer token and cluster id however when I run the notebook it says Import module not found. Can you help me where I'm going wrong please?

```
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: xxxxx
        ScriptType: InlineScript
        Inline: |
          Install-Module -Name azure.databricks.cicd.tools -Force -Scope CurrentUser
        azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion   

    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: xxxxx
        ScriptType: InlineScript
        Inline: |
          Import-Module -Name azure.databricks.cicd.tools
          Add-DatabricksLibrary -BearerToken $(az-bearer-token) -Region $(az-region) -LibraryType "pypi" -LibrarySettings 'azure-identity' -ClusterId 'xxxxxx'
          Add-DatabricksLibrary -BearerToken $(az-bearer-token) -Region $(az-region) -LibraryType "pypi" -LibrarySettings 'azure.keyvault.secrets' -ClusterId 'xxxxx'
        azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

followed by .....

```
   - task: configuredatabricks@0
   - task: DataThirstLtd.databricksDeployScriptsTasks.databricksDeployScriptsTask.databricksDeployScripts@0
   - task: executenotebook@0
```

[image: Library successfully installed on to the cluster]

```
Databricks notebook:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
credential = ClientSecretCredential(directory_id, sp_client_id, sp_client_secret, 'login.microsoftonline.com')

Error message:

ImportError: No module named azure.identity
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation of libraries isn't synchronous - when you execute `Add-DatabricksLibrary` command it calls `install` endpoint of [Libraries REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/libraries), and documentation says:

> The installation is **asynchronous** - it completes in the background after the request.

You may use the [Cluster status REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/libraries#--cluster-status) to check if all libraries have the `INSTALLED` status, and trigger the notebook only after that. (I don't see similar functionality in the `azure.databricks.cicd.tools` library)